# Not sending e-mails ver. 1.9.2

Tags: ce-1.9.2.0

Older versions worked well but after upgrading to version 1.9.2 e-mails don't send anymore. I set up cron with command line :
php -f /home4/myserver_name/public_html/cron.sh 
5min
The only e-mail I get is the cron_daemon sending me the cron.sh file..!!
After researching for hours and trying different solutions I am at my witts end. Nothing worked. Ant help his highly appreciated! Thx in advance!

Comment: Did you check the Magento and Apache (php) logs for any errors?

Comment: thx for reminding me...here is what it shows: HP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so' - /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[10-Nov-2015 09:05:13 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SCRIPT_NAME in /home4/myserver_name/public_html/cron.php on line 40

Comment: So that means you need to install the imagick library on your server

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a missing php library

Comment: First of all...thx for your help and input! Really appreciate it!

Comment: no problem. If you need help with installing I would suggest serverfault.com They're better with servers :)

Comment: Why don't use call cron.php instead?

Comment: You are calling .sh file from PHP! how can you expect it to work ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an incorrect crontab configuration. Sending to ServerFault would lead to it being closed as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem: `php -f /home4/myserver_name/public_html/cron.sh`, you're trying to run a shell file with PHP. You should use one of these:

- `php -f /home4/myserver_name/public_html/cron.php`
- `sh /home4/myserver_name/public_html/cron.sh`

And if that's still not working and you're getting the error messages of missing libraries (as you've commented on your question) but you've them already installed and configured I think you've to check if PHP is using the right `.ini` when running it with CLI:

- Create a `phpinfo.php` file in your `/home4/myserver_name/public_html/` directory with this line: `<?php echo phpinfo();`
- Visit your website with `/phpinfo.php` and check which `.ini` files are loaded
- Run `php --ini` from the terminal and check if it's using the same `.ini` files

If that's not the case, you can use the `-c` parameter: `-c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory`. With that parameter you've to point to the directory of the `.ini` file that's loaded by the server (which you've found in the `phpinfo.php` file you've created). So that could be something like: `php -f /home4/myserver_name/public_html/cron.php -c /home4/myserver_name/` when that's where the `.ini` lives. And don't forget to remove the `phpinfo.php` file!

Comment: I had cron.php before and it did not work! I will look into  it..thx again..really apppreciated!

Comment: You should never invoke the PHP file directly. Not only does it not have job control/sanity checks, but also requires arguments to run properly. Only the shell script should be run.

Comment: Thank you for your input...I guess to use the cron.sh is the correct way...thx again!